# Shuffle matrix using functions (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, function, loops, matrix

I am writing a code that creates a 10x10 matrix using functions and it uses functions to print as well. I am currently making a function that will shuffle the contents of the matrix and print using a function to shuffle the matrix and using the same function to print the first matrix to print out the shuffled matrix. The problem I think I am having with my code is that whenever I print the matrix it is actually not shuffling but actually printing out a brand new matrix. What I have tried is to call the function within the function but that did not seem to work.

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

const int ROW_SIZE = 10;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 10;

void initialize(int [][10], int, int);
void display(int matrix[][10], int, int);
void shuffle(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int, int);


int main() {

    int matrix [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    initialize(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);

    shuffle(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);




    return 0;
}


void initialize(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            matrix[i][j] =  1 + rand() % 99;
        }
    }
}


void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
         cout<< endl;
    }
}



void shuffle(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
    swap(matrix[i],matrix[j]); 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: [OT]: `void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE)` is misleading, as you hide global `ROW_SIZE`/`COLUMN_SIZE` by local parameters. ugly syntax would be: `void display(const int (&matrix)[ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE])`, or keeping your syntax: `void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int RowSize)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your shuffle algorithm is wrong. It also assumes the number of rows is the same as the number of columns, and will invoke undefined behavior if they're not. All it does it march through the matrix swapping whole rows with the inverse counterparts. But after doing half the iterations, it swaps them *back* in the second half. It also makes no swaps for columns whatsoever.

You need to setup a random row and column picker, then swap *that* location with the iteration location of `matrix[i][j]`. The full code, including a modified version of your initializer to setup a sequence matrix (and thus drive home the results of the shuffle visually) is below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

const int ROW_SIZE = 10;
const int COLUMN_SIZE = 10;

void initialize(int [][10], int, int);
void display(int matrix[][10], int, int);
void shuffle(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int, int);


int main() {

    int matrix [ROW_SIZE][COLUMN_SIZE];

    initialize(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);

    shuffle(matrix, ROW_SIZE, COLUMN_SIZE);

    display(matrix, ROW_SIZE,COLUMN_SIZE);




    return 0;
}


void initialize(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    int x = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            matrix[i][j] =  ++x;
        }
    }
}


void display(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    for(int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            cout<< setw(4)<<matrix[i][j]<< " ";
        }
         cout<< endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}



void shuffle(int matrix[][COLUMN_SIZE], int ROW_SIZE, int COLUMN_SIZE){
    
    std::mt19937 prng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> rdist(0, ROW_SIZE-1);
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> cdist(0, COLUMN_SIZE-1);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROW_SIZE; i++) { 
        for(int j = 0; j < COLUMN_SIZE; j++){
            int x = rdist(prng);
            int y = cdist(prng);
            std::swap(matrix[x][y], matrix[i][j]);
        } 
    }
}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
   1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10 
  11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20 
  21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30 
  31   32   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40 
  41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48   49   50 
  51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60 
  61   62   63   64   65   66   67   68   69   70 
  71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80 
  81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90 
  91   92   93   94   95   96   97   98   99  100 

  36   22   28   32   47   29    2   65   10   48 
  76   86   64   56   25    8   91   70   75    6 
  52   40   87   97   23    9   53   39   59   74 
  84   61   43    3   38   69   60   81   83   42 
  19   72   49   67   27   80   44   55   18   16 
  96   37   46   79    4   12   17   41   11   30 
  73   66   71   14   54   77   57   45   88   93 
  63   89  100   33   58   50   85   95   68   26 
  34   35    7    1   51   92   21   90   15   99 
  94   24   62   13   82   31   78    5   20   98
```

Comment: Once again, having matrix as 1D would be "better". here it would allow to use `std::shuffle(std::begin(matrix), std::end(matrix), urgb);` (as IIAC, even a 2D array (and not an array of array) cannot be pedantically treated as "bigger" 1D-array).